# Button to save datagridview back to database

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have the following code which displays data from one of my SQL tables and displays it in a datagridview.

I am now trying to put a save button on the ViewCustomerForm in order to save the records back to my SQL table.

Here is the code to display the data.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=BillingReferenceData; integrated security=yes")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * FROM Customers", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim myDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
        myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "Customers")
        ViewCustomersForm.DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("Customers")
        con.Close()

        ViewCustomersForm.Show()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Could somebody please help me out with the correct syntax for the 'Save' button

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't ask sample codes for tasks like these...
Just try something and ask if you get some problem.
You can do that using either loop through the grid view or using the dataset you get from querying the DB

Comment: And what is the purpose of updating the data when there are no modifications. Are you inserting them again?

Comment: There will be modifications to the data, in the datagridview - These are the changes that I want to write back to my SQL table

Comment: So you can loop through the grid view or if you are saving your modifications in the dataset you can save the dataset yo the database.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            For i As Integer = 0 To dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim strQuery As String = ("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" + dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("ColumnName").Value & ", ") + dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("ColumnName").Value & ");"

                Try
                    Using conn = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
                        Using comm = New SqlCommand(strQuery, conn)
                            conn.Open()
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                Catch generatedExceptionName As InvalidCastException
                End Try
            Next
        End Sub
```

Remember you will still have to chance your variables of your datagridview etc.

grtz

fosa